# Spring cache vs. cachemanger

Tags: spring, ehcache

The following sample from the [Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-store-configuration-ehcache) confuses the heck out of me.

```
<bean id="cacheManager" 
      class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
      p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>

<!-- Ehcache library setup -->
<bean id="ehcache" 
      class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" 
      p:config-location="ehcache.xml"/>
```

The naming convention mandates that `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean` produces a cache *manager*, more precisely it's a `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager` instance. Yet, the bean is called `ehcache` not `ehcachemanager`. The actual `cacheManager`, however, references this bean.

In prose you could say that one is the Ehcache cache manager while the other is the Spring cache manager (which is backed by the former).

It gets worse if you use the `EhCacheFactoryBean`:

```
<bean
  id="myCache"
  class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
  <property name="cacheManager">
    <ref local="ehcache" />
  </property>
```

There's a property called `cacheManager` which references a bean called `ehcache`.

Did I misunderstand anything or is it really that confusing? Bad design or just bad naming in the example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring framework recently introduced [caching abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) with [`org.springframework.cache.CacheManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) central interface. This interface has few built-in implementations, including:

- `ConcurrentMapCacheManager`
- [`EhCacheCacheManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheCacheManager.html)
- `NoOpCacheManager`
- `SimpleCacheManager`

This design allows you to switch caching library without touching application code. As you can see one of these built-in implementations is backed by EhCache. However notice that `EhCacheCacheManager` is just a bridge between Spring caching abstraction and EhCache library. Thus it needs existing [`net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.html). You can either create an instance of this cache manager yourself or take advantage of existing factory bean, namely [`EhCacheManagerFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.html).

I understand it's confusing because of overlapping names, but it should be clear from the above which classes come from which library and why are they used.

Comment: This confirms my understanding was correct. Don't you think `ehcacheManager` would be a more appropriate name for that bean then?

Comment: @MarcelStör: you might be right. Feel free to open [pull-request](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework) with corrected documentation.